# Having issues setting running Meteor app with SSL on AWS Opsworks

Tags: node.js, ssl, meteor, aws-opsworks

My base case is that my Meteor App runs perfectly on Opsworks.
I do a Meteor `build`, tweak the files and all is good (without HTTPS/SSL). I am not using METEORUP. I just upload my tweaked build file and deploy on opsworks.

Also, I am using the out of the box Opsworks HAPROXY loadbalancer.

I then install the SSL certificates for my app and set Meteor to list on `PORT=443` as per screenshot:

[image]

In the browser, I see:

```
503 Service Unavailable

No server is available to handle this request.
```

In the log files I see:

```
Mar  8 03:22:51 nodejs-app1 monit[2216]: 'node_web_app_buzzy' start: /bin/bash
Mar  8 03:23:51 nodejs-app1 monit[2216]: 'node_web_app_buzzy' failed, cannot ope
n a connection to INET[127.0.0.1:443/] via TCPSSL
```

Any ideas welcome

Comment: Hey @aginsburg Can you post your HAPROXY configuration file

Comment: Thanks @nathan thanks - sorry for dumb question, do you know where I can find this on opsworks... I know with Beanstalk it was a bit of a maze.

Comment: Not too familiar with opswork; on another tact, it sounds like your asking meteor to terminate SSL; rather than terminating SSL at HAProxy and then sending regular HTTP to meteor (desired).

Comment: You may be right... I am going to raise this with AWS support as they are struggling as they don't have Meteor experience.

Comment: Here's my haproxy cfg https://gist.github.com/adamgins/740a03dfc65424431a62

Answer (score 0):

Your HAproxy configuration is expecting meteor/node to respond with SSL.

It should instead, terminate SSL and talking to node/meteor in plain HTTP. This is because, meteor doesn't do SSL ; it expects a server in front to handle it.

Solution: 
[Update the `frontend https-in` section to terminate ssl and redirect to the http backend](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04)

```
defaults
   #... add this line to enable the `X-Forwarded-For` header
   option forwardfor
   # ... 

# .... update this section ...
frontend https-in
  mode tcp
  # this bit causes HAProxy to talk TLS rather than just forward the connection
  bind :443 ssl crt /path/to/your/certificate
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  # now direct it to your plain HTTP application
  acl nodejs_application_buzzy_domain_buzzy hdr_end(host) -i buzzy
  use_backend nodejs_app_servers if nodejs_application_buzzy_domain_buzzy
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. Going to try this out now... will need to use custom cookbooks to get the result and being a beginner cook (not even Chef)... may take a bit of fiddling ;-)

Comment: ah I should have added - this is a recipe I had used recently... See line 267 onwards: https://github.com/Buzzy-Buzz/buzzy-opswork-cookbook/blob/master/haproxy/templates/default/haproxy.cfg.erb

Comment: ooops ... ah I should have added - this is a recipe I had used recently... See line 267 onwards: https://github.com/Buzzy-Buzz/buzzy-opswork-cookbook/blob/master/haproxy/templates/default/haproxy.cfg.erb
So do I just modify 269 to include "bind :443 ssl crt /path/to/your/certificate" and then add "reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https" under it?

then do your lines: "acl nodejs_application_buzzy_domain_buzzy hdr_end(host) -i buzzy
  use_backend nodejs_app_servers if nodejs_application_buzzy_domain_buzzy" refer to lines 189 & 223?

Comment: I did try and take a shot at it here... https://github.com/Buzzy-Buzz/buzzy-opswork-cookbook/blob/https-test/haproxy/templates/default/haproxy.cfg.erb but not sure if this is correct?